# How to fix 2 DIVs side by side

Tags: css

I have 2 DIVs like below how can i place it on the page side by side and centered.
Not getting any luck with the below.
Thanks in Advance

Right now my CSS is :

```
#content
  {
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  width:1400px;
  /*width: 1200px;  position: absolute;  top:auto;  bottom:0px;  right:0px;  left:auto; */

}


#left{
    float:left;
    width:700px;   
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;  bottom:720px;  right:700px;  left:auto; 

}

#right{
    width: 700px;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
   top:auto;  bottom:750px;  right:-90px;  left:600; 
}


<div id="content">
            <div id="left">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceScanned">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#004080" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Yellow" />
                    <Columns>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

            </div>



            <div id="right">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMade">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#004080" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Yellow" />
                    <Columns>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            <div style="clear: both;">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the rendered HTML? (As you see it in view: source)

Comment: http://java.sg/creating-html-tables-with-css-and-div/

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS Styles

```
#content
  {
  height: 100%;
  width:1400px;
  margin:0 auto;

}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:700px;   
}

#right{
    width: 700px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Out of the three comments, this is the correct CSS for what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is :

```
#left{
 display:inline;
}

#right{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the only problem i saw in this code was `top:auto`

give top some specific distance. and for horizontal central align use `text-align:center;` in the left & right div